# Add boolean key to plist in Terminal

Tags: macos, bash, shell, unix, terminal

I am currently trying to create a Terminal shell that adds a boolean key called "disabled"  with a true value to an existing plist.

So far I have `defaults write "/System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.AppStoreUpdateAgent" disabled -bool true`

I am I setting the boolean value correctly, or should I not have the `-bool`?
Should "disabled" be in quotes?

Comment: That's a root-owned plist file... so hopefully you're calling "`sudo`" before modifying defaults... and double hopefully you know what you're trying to do.  What are you trying to do, anyways?

Comment: I am disabling a Launch Agent that automatically pops up when a new user logs into a Mac informing the user that they do not have permission to access this Launch Agent (for the update badge on the Mac App Store). I have to manually overwrite the plist normally, but I am trying to automate the process a bit.

Comment: Have you looked at [the man page for `defaults`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/defaults.1.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`defaults write /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.AppStoreUpdateAgent disabled -bool true` should be correct. `disabled` doesn't need to be in quotes and `-bool true` should work, but as @MichaelDautermann mentioned, you would need to run it as root.

You could also unload the job with `launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.AppStoreUpdateAgent.plist`.

```
-w       Overrides the Disabled key and sets it to false. In previous ver-
         sions, this option would modify the configuration file. Now the
         state of the Disabled key is stored elsewhere on-disk.
```